# Unable to display two plots in different tabs with mdl

Tags: javascript, d3.js, material-design, material-design-lite

I am playing around with javascript and d3 for only a week now, so I am quite new on the topic.

**Required** - A website with three tabs, each showing a different chart/plot.

I added a plot to the first tab, and it works perfectly.

**Issue** - On adding the second plot in tab two, the first plot does not display well, and the second one doesn't show up at all.

I have searched the web but only got solutions for bootstrap, which seems different to me.

I am using the same .js file for both plots, just opening two different .tsv files in it and calling different functions inside the .js file.

My html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
              minimum-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Material Design Lite">

    <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="js/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

  <body>
      <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title"> Dashboard</span>

      <!-- Tabs -->
      <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Tab1</a>
        <a href="#scroll-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab2</a>
      </div>

    </header>

    <main id="app" class="mdl-layout__content">

    <!-- TAB 1 -->
    <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="scroll-tab-1">
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="mdl-grid">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                <h4 class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col" > Plot1 </h4>
            </div>

        <div class="plotAndNavi locator-chart" id="chart1" style="background-color: white;">
            <div class="ul-holder">
                <ul class="dateselect">
                    <li><div class="vcenter"></div>
                        <button class="button"
                                id="picker"
                                onclick="initialize(0);"
                                value = "0">0 %
                                          </li>
                        <li><div class="vcenter"></div>
                        <button class="button"
                                id="picker"
                                onclick="initialize(5);"
                                value = "5">5 %
                               </li>
                </ul> 
            </div>    
            <div class="clearboth"></div>
        </div>
        </div>   
      </section>

      <!-- TAB 2 -->

    <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-2">
      <div class="page-content">

      <div class="plotAndNavi2 locator-chart" id="chart2" style="background-color: white;">
            <div class="ul-holder">
                <ul class="dateselect">
                    <li><div class="vcenter">
                            <button class="button"
                            onclick="addDays(-1);return false;">Previous</a></div></li>
                    <li><div class="vcenter">Date<br><input
                            type="text" id="datepicker" disabled="disabled" value="loading..." /></div></li>
                    <li><div class="vcenter"><button class="nextDayButton"
                            onclick="addDays(1);return false;">Next</a></div></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="clearboth"></div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </section>

        </main>

    <!--    Material Design Lite version -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.blue-light_blue.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="css/style.css" />

        <!-- make tabs work -->
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

    <!--    VueJs & App -->
                 <script src="js/helper.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The helper.js looks as follows:

```
"use strict";

Date.prototype.ymd = function() {
   var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
   var dd  = this.getDate();
   return this.getFullYear() + "-" + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + "-" + (dd >= 10 ? dd : "0" + dd);
};

var data;
var yAxisGlobalMax = 980;

var initialize = function(value) {

   ...Do Stuff...

    updateGraph(filteredData);

};

var initializeDatepicker = function() {

    ...Do stuff...

        updateGraph(data.filter(function(row) { return row.date == currentHistory.ymd(); }));
};

var addDays = function(anzahlTage) {
    var currentDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + anzahlTage);
    $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', currentDate);
    $("#datepicker").change();
};

var validDatepickerDate = function(date) {
    return data.filter(function(row) { return row.date == date.ymd(); }).length == 0
        ? [false, '']
        : [true, ''];
};


// Dimensions
....

// Chart
var chart = d3.select("#Simulation")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Axes
chart.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -40)
    .attr("class", "axislabel")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .text("title y");
chart.append("text")
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr("y", height + 40)
    .attr("class", "axislabel")
    .text("title x");

// Axes calculation
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);   

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}

d3.tsv("file1.tsv", type, function(error, dataNew){

    data = dataNew;
    console.log(data);

    initializeDatepicker();

    var todayYMD = (new Date()).ymd();
    var maxDate = data.reduce(function(previous,current){ return previous.date > current.date ? previous : current });
    var minDate = data.reduce(function(previous,current){ return previous.date < current.date ? previous : current });
    //yAxisGlobalMax = data.reduce(function(previous,current){ return previous.value > current.value ? previous : current }).value;

    var dp = $("#datepicker");
    dp.attr("value", todayYMD);
    dp.datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(minDate.date) );
    dp.datepicker("option", "maxDate", new Date(maxDate.date) );
    dp.removeAttr("disabled");
    dp.change();

    d3.tsv("file2.tsv", type, function(error, dataNew2){

        data = dataNew2;
        console.log(data);

        initialize(0);

    });

});

var updateGraph = function(data) {
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
    //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
    y.domain([0, yAxisGlobalMax]);

    chart.select(".y.axis")
        .transition().duration(500).ease("sin-in-out")
        .call(yAxis);
    chart.select(".x.axis")
        .transition().duration(500).ease("sin-in-out")
        .call(xAxis);

    var bars = chart.selectAll(".bar").data(data, function(d) { return x(d.name) });
    bars.exit().remove();
    bars.transition().duration(500)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); });
    bars.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
        .attr("y", y(0))
        .attr("height", 0)
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .transition().duration(500) //.ease("elastic")
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); });

    var texts = chart.selectAll(".barlabel").data(data, function(d) { return x(d.name) });
    texts.exit().remove();
    $("text.barlabel").css("font-size", "1.199em");
    texts.transition().duration(500)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name) + (width - margin.left - margin.right)/2/data.length; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value) + 3; })
        .styleTween("font-size", function(d) { return d3.interpolate(this.style.getPropertyValue("font-size"), "1.2em");})
        .text(function(d) { return d.value > 10 ? d.value : ""; })
    texts.enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "barlabel")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name) + (width - margin.left - margin.right)/2/data.length; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value) + 3; })
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.value > 10 ? d.value : ""; })
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 1);
};
```

I really have no clue where the issue might be Please, I would be thankful for any help!